# How to Set background image with navigation bar in react-native using react-navigation

Tags: image, react-native, react-navigation, background-image, react-navigation-drawer

I have to achieve Below output :

[image: Actual image - Header with navigation bar]

What I achieved

[image: Here, In red mark extra space is there, Also I used Navigation drawer and Header from the React-Navigation library. Black highlighted area is Header and which is clearly shown in the output. I need to remove that header highlighted part and wants output same as original design]

Here is My source code :

```
 return (
        <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/images/home_bg.png')} style={{
            height: 185,
            width: '100%',

        }}>
            <Header style={{
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            }}
                androidStatusBarColor={"#EB7D16"} >
                <View style={{ flex: 0.5, alignItems: 'center', alignContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                    <Left>{LeftIcon}</Left>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 4, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <CustomSearchBar />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 0.5, alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Right>{RightIcon}</Right>
                </View>
            </Header>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Image resizeMode="contain" source={require('../../assets/icons/logo.png')} style={{ height: '50%', width: '50%', marginTop: 20 }}>
                </Image>
            </View>
        </ImageBackground >
    );
```

I used Image Background and then Set Header component on that module.

Here, I set ImageBackground height: 185, width: '100%', which is wrong way and it's not responsive for all devices. I also use windows.height and windows.width but it's also not working, Kindly share proper way for setting this background Image and How to achieve may targeted output.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you need to make status bar "translucent" so that background image starts from top.

**try this and add in your main render of screen**

```
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";

 ...

<StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will surely use your suggestion for future use. Currently issue was my background image . I replaced it with other image and resolved! @Mehran Khan

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by my slef.. actually issue with background image.

Thank you all for time!